# yum update dependency in rhel

Tags: rhel, yum

I am fairly new to rhel and yum. I have a hosted rpm repository and when I try to update rhel7 system using `yum update` command. I am getting below error. But when I check the repository, it contains all the rpm packages.

```
Error: Package: samba-client-4.10.16-9.el7_9.x86_64 (@/samba-client-4.10.16-9.el7_9.x86_64)
Requires: samba-common = 4.10.16-9.el7_9
Removing: samba-common-4.10.16-9.el7_9.noarch (@hs)
samba-common = 4.10.16-9.el7_9
Updated By: samba-common-4.10.16-13.el7_9.noarch (hs)
samba-common = 4.10.16-13.el7_9
Available: samba-common-4.1.12-24.el7_1.x86_64 (hs)
samba-common = 4.1.12-24.el7_1
```

I tried `yum clean all` and it's same result. Any help on this will be much appreciated.

update:
The custom repository contains all the packages and versions listed in the above output.

Comment: No one knows what your custom repo contains, so you're unlikely to get any answers.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov actually the custom repo contains all the packages and versions listed on the error/output. Updated the question.

Comment: DO you need to host (in custom repo) packages with already exist in official RHEL repos?

Comment: we have an offline machines - which do not have access to RHEL repos. So we repotrack the rpm from subs-servers and keep it in custom repo's. @RomeoNinov

Comment: Try to update the index of repo

Comment: I don't know why or how - but just removing the ```samba-client-4.10.16-9.el7_9.x86_64``` solved the problem.